# React native fingerprint library with CryptoObject support

Tags: android, ios, react-native, fingerprint, time-and-attendance

I am building an attendance application with React Native. The students will have to indicate their presence in school by scanning their thumbprint. I have seen several libraries that utilize the Android and iOS fingerprint scanners but none has support for `CryptoObject` where I can access the Asymmetric keys generated when the user scans their fingerprint and I can save it to a server like Firebase.

Comment: Keep in mind that Android's fingerprint API doesn't provide a way of identifying _who_ authenticated. It only tells you whether the currently scanned fingerprint matched _any_ of the fingerprints enrolled on the device. Also, devices may have a fairly low limit for how many fingerprints you can enroll (e.g. 5). The scanner is really only meant to be used by the device's owner.

Comment: You will likely need to use an external finger print scanner to make this work. Using facial recognition may be a better approach.  I have made this work on iOS and Android using React Native and the AWS Rekognition service.

Comment: Thanks @TomAranda, quite resourceful piece, I will look out for an external thumbprint that I can integrate, either using Nodejs or Laravel for the backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution, so I think I should drop it here.

This [library](https://github.com/joshuachinemezu/react-native-biometrics) solved it for me. Very resourceful

Comment: Did you use an external Finger Print Scanner.?